# openssl wrong certs directory

Tags: linux, openssl, arm

I've crosscompiled openssl for an ARM device running linux 2.6.36.

If I try to make a connection to a site using:

```
openssl s_client -connect google.com:443
```

I will receive an **error 20: unable to get local issuer certificate**.

If I run:

```
openssl s_client -connect google.com:443 -CAfile=/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
```

the connection will succeed without errors.

**openssl version -d** returns `OPENSSLDIR: /usr/lib/ssl` which structure is the following:

```
ls -lh /usr/lib/ssl/
lrwxrwxrwx   1   root   root   14   Jan 1 1970 certs -> /etc/ssl/certs
lrwxrwxrwx   1   root   root   20   Jan 1 1970 openssl.cnf -> /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf
lrwxrwxrwx   1   root   root   17   Jan 1 1970 private -> /etc/ssl/private
lrwxrwxrwx   1   root   root   22   Jan 1 1970 misc 
lrwxrwxrwx   1   root   root   34   Jan 1 1970 openssl.cnf.dist
```

I need openssl correctly configured in order to run a software which I have developed, so I can't set evertytime the -CAfile flags beacuse I will not directly call openssl s_client.

How could I set the directory in which openssl search for certificates?
I'm trying to solve this problem since some days without success.